# Generate deep link to custom ms teams app that is not listed on ms teams app store

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an MS Teams app that is not listed on the MS Teams app store. I was wondering if I could generate a deep link to this app even though it's not listed on the MS Teams app store? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can create a deep link to something within your (unpublished) app (a link to a tab would work, for example), but not to the app itself. Where do you expect this link to lead to? I mean, normally the app link would lead to install the app from the store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2